# How to count amount of related components on an adjacency matrix

Tags: java, graph

I have to create a method that returns the amount of groups in the graph
but i dont find the way to do it,i just need a guide of how i should do it,thanks you.
[Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cEuK.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.